# Voigt function from Convolution theorem

Tags: fourier-transform, gaussian-integral

I am currently reading this paper on lasers by [G. M. Stéphan, T. T. Tam, S. Blin, P. Besnard, and M. Têtu](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.71.043809).

The author considered various noise sources present in the laser experiment and obtained the power spectral density using Wiener Khinchin theorem as Voigt profile in Eq. \eqref{2} reproduced below
$$
I_E(\omega)= E_0^2\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sigma} K(X,Y) \label{2}\tag{10}
$$
The general definition of Voigt profile is the convolution of a Gaussian and a Lorentzian function.  But the author uses Wiener Khinchin theorem to obtain Voigt from Eq. \eqref{1} (again reproduced below).
$$
I_E(\omega)= \frac{E^2}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{i(\omega-\omega_0)\tau+\Gamma\tau-(\sigma\tau/2)}d\tau+ \text{c.c.} \label{1}\tag{9}
$$
The author somehow modifies Eq. \eqref{1} which is an integral of a Gaussian function to Eq. \eqref{2} which is Voigt.  I don't understand the mathematical steps involved in going from Eq. \eqref{1} to Eq. \eqref{2}.

My attempt: I tried to apply convolution theorem on Eq. \eqref{1} which can written as product of a Gaussian and an exponentially decaying function.  Fourier transform of Gaussian is a Gaussian and exponentially decaying function is a Lorentzian. From convolution theorem Eq. \eqref{1} is simply the convolution of Gaussian and Lorentizian which gives a Voigt?  Is this correct way to understand the derivation?

Comment: I find your question a bit hard to interpret. How do the parameters $E_0$, $X$, and $Y$ in formula (10) relate to the parameters $E$, $\omega_0$, and $\Gamma$ in formula (9)? I think the approach described in the last paragraph is misguided as formula (9) doesn't look like a convolution to me. All terms in the exponent are a function of the integration variable $\tau$ whereas a convolution is defined as $[f(\tau) * g(\tau)](t)=\int\limits _{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau)\,   g(t-\tau )\, d\tau$. If you're viewing formula (9) as a convolution, what is your definition of $t$?

Comment: can you link a downloadable paper?

Comment: @StevenClark Yes, I think the Fourier transform of two functions $f(x) g(x)$ is same as convolution of Fourier transforms $F(\omega)$ an $G(\omega)$.

Comment: @StarbucksMediumCup ArXiV version is not available